# VHDL constants returning 10500 error in quartus II

Tags: binary, vhdl, constants, quartus

I need to initialize a number of constants for seven segment display uses, but I am having some issues with them. Whenever I compile

```
constant displayR : type := b"01010000";
```

I get

```
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at VendingMachine.vhd(62) near text "constant";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("constant" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement
```

What do I need to do to get the constant to compile correctly?

Comment: `type` is a reserved word and cannot be used as an identifier.

Comment: ... but apart from that, the declaration is probably in the wrong place since the parser is expecting concurrent statements. So move it to the declaration region.

Comment: There are four places suitable for concurrent statements. An entity declaration statement part (for a concurrent assertion statement or passive concurrent procedure call),  an architecture body, a block statement and a generate statement. Each of these are preceded by a declarative region. Have you placed this declaration outside of (after the `begin`) the preceding declarative region of one of these? An actual answer to your question requires a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to declare a subtype for your seven segment display:

```
subtype t_display is bit_vector(7 downto 0);
constant displayR : t_display := "01010000";
```